# Configuring nginx for my own purposes

Tags: nginx

Can anyone help me please with editing `nginx.conf` according to the tasks below. I've done the basic configuration. Here a list of options that must be set also (I haven't done it yet):

```
1.Image files should be served by nginx with "Expires: 21 days" header added 
2.Logging of requests to "/somelogo.ico" should be disabled. All other requests should be proxied to another web server running on
local IP address on port 8080
3.Virtual host should accept requests to all "test.org" subdomains;
```

Here my `nginx.conf`

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;



events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
 '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
 '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/test.org/access.log  main;


   server {
      location / {
                    root     /var/www/test.org/html;
             }
       location /images/ {
                root  /var/www/test.org/images;
             }
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

if the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080/mapped_dir/;
    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
}
```

then

```
test.org/xxxxx will proxy to  http://127.0.0.1:8080/mapped_dir/xxxxx
```

conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
 '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
 '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/test.org/access.log  main;


   server {
      listen 80;
      # handle requests containing anything.test.org in the HTTP header hosts field
      server_name *.test.org;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080/mapped_dir/;
        proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
    }
       location /images/ {
                root  /var/www/test.org/images;
                add_header "Expires:" "21 days" always;
             }
       # turn off logging for requests to /somelogo.ico
       location /somelogo.ico {
             access_log off;
          }
       }
```

#### info on the relevant directives

- [access log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log)
- [server](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)
- [modify headers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_headers)